# Google sheets query between two spreadsheets dependent on items in each

Tags: google-sheets

Essentially I have two separate spreadsheets, each with a list. One list is in numerical order, one isn't, and the one in order has a checkbox next to it.

On spreadsheet one I have the sheet test1, and on spreadsheet two I have the sheet test2.

test1:

- item1  (checkbox)
- item2  (checkbox)
- item3  (checkbox)
- item4  (checkbox)
- item5  (checkbox)

test2:

- item3
- item2
- item4
- item1
- item5

What I'd like to do is take the value of the checkbox next to each item, and place it next to its own item on the other spreadsheet. Now I've figured out importing a range from another spreadsheet, but not so much referencing both the other spreadsheet and the current spreadsheet in the same function.

Here's what I've got so far

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet1url","test1!A:B"),"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1="__",0)
```

The blank spot is where I'd like to reference A/Col1 of spreadsheet two test2. Just throwing in test2!A:A doesn't seem to work.

Am I on the right track at least, or should I be trying something else entirely? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula does heavy calculations [`importrange`] each cell.

Try:

`=filter(vlookup(A:A, IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet1url","test1!A:B") ,2,) , A:A <> "")`

Comment: Works wonderfully! Thank you! I don't know much when it comes to functions so whenever I start a new project I mostly just end up using whatever basic function I can find that works first, which does lead to some problems at times. Thanks for giving me something new to mess around with!